# Animate cloth squishing breast with physics

Tags: physics

I have a character with breast physics made with cloth simulation and some clothes (made also with simulation) but I'm trying to add an squish effect to the interaction of the breast and the clothes, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Maybe this video will help you https://youtu.be/sgnA3bxykdI

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a mesh deform modifier for squishy things:

[image]

Once  bound, you can animate the mesh deformer to deform the modified mesh.  Here, I'm using a shapekey on the mesh deformer to do so, but you can also use an armature or physics.

If you want to interpolate smoothly from something mesh deformed to something undeformed, you can use vertex groups, or you can create a shell for your mesh deformer:

[image]

Notice the normals-- it's not a solidified mesh, both surfaces' normals point outwards.  Animate the inside and leave the outside unanimated, and you'll get smooth interpolation from deformed, at the bound border of the inner shell, with undeformed, at the bound border of the outer shell.

If used in conjunction with an armature, I'll usually use a bone-parented mesh deformer with a dynamic bind:

[image]

The bone-parented mesh deformer follows the bone by transformation, echoing the mesh deformation; then, it deforms the mesh in the new positions of the deformer and the modified mesh.

(You could also do the mesh deformation before the armature, with an unparented mesh deformer, but then you can't reasonably animate the deformer with physics.)

If there are multiple layers, and they have reasonably similar topology (or enough vertex density, distance that it doesn't matter), you can bind both to the same mesh deformer and get the same deformation:

[image]

Comment: This is like what I already have, I made a mesh wit the shape of the breast and bound it to the body with mesh deform and apply cloth physics, then i parent that area to some bones with a few modifiers that allow me to have a good jiggle physics and interaction/deformation with external objects but when I try with clothes the mesh goes thru the breast, i solution this by adding collision modifier on both but now it acts as if the breast was A solid object even if it's jiggling, and if I turn the collision of in the breast it acts as if the cloth is a solid object with cloth physics

Comment: Use the same deformer for clothes and body to prevent clipping.  But really, it sounds like you have a lot of details that you neglected to mention in your question, and maybe you should ask a question that focuses on what you want to achieve, what you've done so far, and how what you've done so far falls short for you.